# How to filter certain words from selected text using XPath?

Tags: xpath

To select the text here:

```
     Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot
```

from this HTML structure:

```
<div id="entry-2" class="item-asset asset hentry">
  <div class="asset-header">
    <h2 class="asset-name entry-title">
      <a rel="bookmark" href="http://blahblah.com/politics-democrat">Pelosi Q&amp;A</a>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="asset-content entry-content">
    <div class="asset-body">
     <p>Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I apply following XPath expression to select the text inside `asset-body`:

```
//div[contains(
            div/h2[
              contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' asset-name ')
              and
              contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' entry-title ')
            ]/a[@rel='bookmark']/@href
         ,'democrat')
        ]/div/div[
           contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' asset-body ')
           ]//text()
```

**How would I sanitize the following words from the text:**

```
Alpha
Charlie
Echo
```

**So that I end up with only the following text in this example:**

```
Bravo Delta
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and for an XPath 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would I sanitize the following words from the text:

```
Alpha 
Charlie 
Echo
```

So that I end up with only the following text in this example:

```
Bravo Delta
```

**This can't be done in XPath 1.0 alone** -- you'll need to get the text in the host language and do the replacement there.

**In XPath 2.0 one can use the `replace()` function**:

```
replace(replace(replace($vText, ' Alpha ', ''), ' Charlie ', ''), ' Echo ')
```

Answer (score 3):

With XPath 1.0 supposing uniques NMTokens:

```
concat(substring-before(concat(' ',$Node,' '),' Alpha '),
       substring-after(concat(' ',$Node,' '),' Alpha '))
```

As you can see, this becomes very verbose (and bad performance).

With XPath 2.0:

```
string-join(tokenize($Node,' ')[not(.=('Alpha','Charlie','Echo'))],' ')
```